# C# WFA - Can't move with arrow keys after clicking on button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picturebox which is moved around the form with the arrow keys. (Using the Key_Down and Key_Up events).
While moving the pbx, if space is pressed on top of a certain label, a button appears.

The problem is that after clicking on the button, I can't move the pbx with the arrow keys again, unless I click outside the form and then click back into it.

I tried

```
private void btnAnswer1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Button code
            this.Activate();
        }
```

to refocus the form after clicking on the button, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: I guess you are moving the `PictureBox` using some kind of `Key-Press` Event handler which is attached to the form right?

Comment: Key_Down event (and Key_Up event), yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you didn't use `Form.KeyPreview` Property. If you set this  property to `True` in the form constructor. The form event handlers should able to receive the event properly.

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress,
>   KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have
>   completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to
>   the control with focus.